# Filling NA row values with nearest right side row value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na, zoo

I want to convert the given dataframe from

```
             c1     c2   c3   c4    c5
    VEG PUFF <NA>    12  <NA>  <NA> 78.43
CHICKEN PUFF <NA>    16  <NA>  88.24 <NA>
BAKERY Total <NA>   <NA>  28   <NA> 84.04
```

to

```
             c1     c2  
    VEG PUFF 12     78.43   
CHICKEN PUFF 16     88.24    
BAKERY Total 28     84.04
```

I tried  two methods but i didnt get accurate results it is sometimes taking left side row value

```
step1 <-  t(na.locf(t(df), fromLast=T))
step2 <-  t(na.locf(t(step1), fromLast=F))

library(dplyr)
MyReplace = function(data) {data %>% t %>% na.locf(.,,T) %>% na.locf %>% t
```

Comment: About your description, do you feel that the example is simplistic to not convey what you described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

As there was lot of confusion on the expected output, updating the answer as suggested by @DavidArenburg using a `tidyverse`  solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  gather(variable, value, -rowname) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate(indx = row_number()) %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  spread(indx, value)

#        rowname   `1`   `2`
#*        <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 BAKERY_Total    28 84.04
#2 CHICKEN_PUFF    16 88.24
#3     VEG_PUFF    12 78.43
```

---

Another solution could be

```
library(data.table)
temp <- apply(df, 1, function(x) data.frame(matrix(x[!is.na(x)], nrow = 1)))
rbindlist(temp, fill = T)
```

---

**Previous Answer**

If I have understand you correctly, you are trying to replace `NA` values in a row with the latest non-NA value in the same row

We can use `na.locf` with `fromLast` set as `TRUE`

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) na.locf(x, fromLast = T, na.rm = F)))


#             c1 c2    c3    c4    c5
#VEG_PUFF     12 12 78.43 78.43 78.43
#CHICKEN_PUFF 16 16 88.24 88.24    NA
#BAKERY_Total 28 28 28.00 84.04 84.04
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `na.omit`

```
t(apply(df, 1, na.omit))
#             [,1]  [,2]
#VEG PUFF       12 78.43
#CHICKEN PUFF   16 88.24
#BAKERY Total   28 84.04
```

#### Update

Based on the excel data showed

```
lst <- apply(df, 1, na.omit)
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
row.names(df2) <- row.names(df)
```

---

Or another option is `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE), id.var = 'rn', 
         na.rm = TRUE), rn~ paste0("c", rowid(rn)), value.var = "value")
#             rn c1    c2  c3
#1: BAKERY Total 28 84.04  NA
#2: CHICKEN PUFF 16 88.24 143
#3:     VEG PUFF 12 78.43  NA
```

To provide a reproducible example,

```
df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c(NA, NA, NA), c2 = c(12L, 16L, NA), c3 = c(NA, 
NA, 28L), c4 = c(NA, 88.24, NA), c5 = c(78.43, 143, 84.04)), .Names = c("c1", 
"c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("VEG PUFF", 
"CHICKEN PUFF", "BAKERY Total"))

lst <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {
               x1 <- unlist(df1[i,])
               x1[complete.cases(x1)]})
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
row.names(df2) <- row.names(df1)
```

The above approach is similar to the `apply` method except that we can be always sure that this output a `list` (in the `apply` - it can vary.  When the number of elements are the same after removing the NA, it will output a `matrix`, in other cases a `list`).  So, we loop over the sequence of rows, remove the `NA` elements, pad `NA` at the end to make lengths of `list` elements same and then `rbind`

---

Or another option is `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`

```
ind <- which(!is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
matrix(df[ind[order(ind[,1]),]], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, 
            dimnames = list(row.names(df), paste0("c", 1:2)))
#             c1    c2
#VEG PUFF     12 78.43
#CHICKEN PUFF 16 88.24
#BAKERY Total 28 84.04
```

Comment: your approch is correct but i am facing issues while applying same concept to this xls file         https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzOpodJQqn6cdFdFUDVaUDZnbE0

Comment: the dataframe which i gave you is minimal one but i had huge one

Comment: @secondmethod i want new data to be cut and move not copy and move .If it is copying it is not i want

Comment: @Yeah i want where  wherever na is there it must replace with the value which is near to it(row wise which is not na) once the value is moved it must look at another value in same row so i will get a dataframe without na's

Comment: @columns:NO it can be any number of columns its like shifting the values which are on right side if na's are there

Comment: @konerunikhil  Suppose the values are `12 NA NA 12 23 NA 32 NA NA` what will be the expected for that row? and another instance `NA 13 NA NA 12` then how do you want to have the expected output aligned?

Comment: first row :12 12 23 32          and second row  :13 12 NA NA