# How to fill values from left to right without over writing entries?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a whole bunch of invertebrates identified to varying taxonomic resolutions.  What I would like to do though is to read through each row in my dataframe and then fill in the gaps with whatever is to the left of the empty space, without overwriting any per-existing entries.

My data frame goes well beyond the bounds shown here so I need to be able to do this for whatever number of rows are in the dataframe but be able to stop at a specified point (i.e. Genus/Species).

This is part of my data frame:

```
       df <- structure(list(Phylum = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Annelida", "Arthropoda"
), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Arachnida", 
"Chilopoda", "Clitellata", "Insecta", "Malacostraca"), class = "factor"), 
    Subclass = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "Acari", "Pterygota"), class = "factor"), 
    Order = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", "Amphipoda", "Araneae", "Archaeognatha", 
    "Blattodea (cockroaches)", "Coleoptera"), class = "factor"), 
    Suborder = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), Family = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Carabidae"), class = "factor"), Subfamily = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Platyninae"), class = "factor"), `Genus/Species` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Ctenognathus sp."), class = "factor")), row.names = 7:20, class = "data.frame")
```

So for the second row in the data frame it would look something like this:

```
Phylum        Class          Subclass         Order        Suborder     
Arthropoda    Malacostraca   Malacostraca     Amphipoda    Amphipoda                                             

Family       Subfamily    Genus/Species
Amphipoda    Amphipoda    Amphipoda
```

How can I do this? Is there a good way to do this with tidyverse?

Comment: Maybe this post will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438019/filling-na-row-values-with-nearest-right-side-row-value-in-r

Comment: That is pretty close but it looks like the OP wanted to reduce this columns to just two filled with the right side. There was one answer by Ronak Shah that looked very similar to what I was after: `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) na.locf(x, fromLast = T, na.rm = F)))` but it doesn't seem to work for my data frame, and I don't understand the code well enough to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Using the `zoo` package, try `as.data.frame(t(na.locf(t(df))))`

Comment: It might be nice to use `dput(droplevels(df))` to reduce the size of the pasted example significantly.

Comment: I think I figured out why that other code wasn't working... The empty cells were being recognised as `""` rather than an `NA`. Your code worked after I used: `df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("^$|^ $", NA, x))` Feel free to chuck that in the answers if you would like the credit!

Comment: @thelatemail - thank you! I have always wondered about how to make the data sets easier to look at. I will update now to make it more readable.

Comment: I don't see any blanks or NAs in the data you posted. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hahahaha whoops - I made the correction that thelatemail suggested and must have accidentally done it on the filled dataset. @camille find the corrected data there now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `zoo` package you can use the `na.locf` function after transposing the matrix with `t()`. You will want to replace your missing values with `NA` before.

```
library(zoo)
df %>% 
  t() %>%   # Transpose 
  na.locf() %>% # fill columns with previous non NA value
  t() # Transpose back
```