# R dynamically merge multiple columns with NA into a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Is there a way to dynamically merge columns with NA values?

```r
tibble(
  x = c(1:2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  y = c(NA, NA, 4:7, NA),
  z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9)
)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA
2     2    NA    NA
3    NA     4    NA
4    NA     5    NA
5    NA     6    NA
6    NA     7    NA
7    NA    NA     9
```

expect:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA
2     2    NA    NA
3     4     4    NA
4     5     5    NA
5     6     6    NA
6     7     7    NA
7     9    NA     9
```

This example is a read from an xlsx file, so in some cases the column `y`or `z` may not exist

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671205/fill-missing-values-rowwise-right-left or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438019/filling-na-row-values-with-nearest-right-side-row-value-in-r

Comment: `coalesce` is not mentioned on these sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first non-NA value from each row :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = na.omit(c_across())[1]) %>%
  ungroup

#      x     y     z result
#  <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1    NA    NA      1
#2     2    NA    NA      2
#3    NA     4    NA      4
#4    NA     5    NA      5
#5    NA     6    NA      6
#6    NA     7    NA      7
#7    NA    NA     9      9
```

In base R :

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) na.omit(x)[1])
```

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah. Could you please assist with my answer. How can I get the existing colnames of a dataframe into `coalesce` function. I tried ` select(df, {{vars}}) %>%
  mutate(result = coalesce(.)) `. But this does not the job. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `do.call`, `do.call(coalesce, df)`. If you want to consider selected columns you can use `do.call(coalesce, df[vars])`

Comment: Thank you Ronak. This helped to get a more general solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
With the help of Ronak. See comments: Now it should work for df with different columns: More general solution for `coalesce` in combination with `do.call`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
  x = c(1:2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  y = c(NA, NA, 4:7, NA)
)

df %>%
  mutate(result = do.call(coalesce, df))
```

Output:

```
      x     y result
  <int> <int>  <int>
1     1    NA      1
2     2    NA      2
3    NA     4      4
4    NA     5      5
5    NA     6      6
6    NA     7      7
7    NA    NA     NA
```

**First answer**
This is a job for `coalesce` from `dplyr` package: finds the first non-missing value at each position.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(result = coalesce(x,y,z))
```

Output:

```
      x     y     z result
  <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA      1
2     2    NA    NA      2
3    NA     4    NA      4
4    NA     5    NA      5
5    NA     6    NA      6
6    NA     7    NA      7
7    NA    NA     9      9
```

Comment: but if `z` not exist coalesce return a error

Comment: Please see my edit. With the help of Ronak now it should also work more general.